# Why the second printf statement overlaps the first one on linux console

Tags: c, gcc, printf

The first `printf` statement prints find but the second one overlaps it. Whats the issue here and how can I fix it?

```
void student(char *name, char *id)
{
  char nme[50];
  strcpy(nme,name);
  //printf("%s",nme);
  nme[strcspn(nme, "\n")] = '\0';
  printf("\n\nWelcome %s ",nme);
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  printf("Loading your Account");
  int i=0;
                while (i<3) {
                        sleep(1);
                        printf(".");
                        i++;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `name` ends with `\r\n` because it was created on Windows and then read in a Linux subsytem or with mode `rb`. Changing the `"\n"` in the `strcspn` cal to `"\r\n"` will probably fix the problem.

You have to watch out for Windows line-endings if you're working in a mixed system. In cases like this, it's often helpful to use a tool like `hd` which prints files out in hexadecimal as well as character format.